# .click() after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, persistence

I am trying url persistence for the first time, and after a page load, I have the elements that I want to click from the URL.  When I load the page, the .click() does not register, but if i type it in the console, it performs correctly.   I have tried placing the code(specifically the `(function persistence(formvals){...})();`) in the (document).ready(function(){...}) section, but that did not work.  How do I get the .click() to register AFTER the page load, and on each element that should be clicked?

url: http://specialorange.org/resume/index.html?gc_abstract_heading&gc_ba_analysis

the two ids of these sections are :
`gc_abstract_heading` and 
`gc_ba_analysis`, so `$(gc_abstract_heading).click()` in the console works, just not in the code.

code:

```
var formvals = {};
var keyval = location.search.replace('?', '').split('&');
$.each(keyval, function () {
    var splitval = this.split('=');
    formvals[splitval[0]] = splitval[1];
});
console.log(keyval);
console.log(formvals);

(function persistence(formvals) {
    for ( i=0 ; i < keyval.length ; i++ ) {
        console.log(keyval[i]);         
        $(keyval[i]).click();
    };
})();
```

Please note that this code is not on the live page, it is on my local site for testing.  The persistence section on the live page is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var formvals = {};
    var keyval = location.search.replace('?', '').split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < keyval.length; i++) {
        console.log('Trigger click on: '+keyval[i]);
        $('#'+keyval[i]).click();
    };
});
```

First I've added document-ready, so the function does not fire until it's ready. Second; the click-handler need `#` as a prefix if the name in the url points towards an id. If it's a class you change `#` with `.`.

Answer (score 0):

Quick stab in the dark here but I allways find if your doing stuff with click in persistance or after the dom its safer to use the live click in jquery.

```
$(keyval[i]).live("click",function(){});
```

Comment: as of jQuery 1.7, the `live` method is deprecated

Comment: true if your using 1.7 its better to use .on() or .delegate()

Comment: I can use .on() even though the user isn't 'click'ing the elements?

Answer (score 0):

you must call `persistence()` on `document load` (or ready) and also the `formvals` declaration:

```
function persistence(formvals) {
    for ( i=0 ; i < keyval.length ; i++ ) {
        console.log(keyval[i]);         
        $(keyval[i]).click();
    };
}

$(function() {
    var formvals = {};
    var keyval = location.search.replace('?', '').split('&');
    $.each(keyval, function () {
        var splitval = this.split('=');
        formvals[splitval[0]] = splitval[1];
    });
    console.log(keyval);
    console.log(formvals);

    persistence(formvals);
});
```

Comment: does `document load` mean the function `$(document).ready(function () {..});` ?

Comment: onload events occurs a little later than onready (when all content is loaded).
$(function(){ ... }) is a shorthand to document ready.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery Selector is missing the '#' if you are targeting IDs.